# Expand link div and add links within it

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to do is, I have a div box with a link (link 1). It an "a href" inside a div with no title so you can click on the whole div. What I want is for this to behave the way it does but also expand and reveal two more links when you hover over it (link 2 and 3) and hide when you mouseout.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/83rV2.png

The closest I've gotten is this bit of code.

Java:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showhide(id, visibility) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<div id="button"> <a href='/page' onMouseOver="showhide('divContent','inline');"
onMouseOut="showhide('divContent','none');"
onfocus="showhide('divContent','inline')";
onBlur="showhide('divContent','none')";></a> <div id="divContent">Link</div>
</div>
```

Problem with this is, the divContent div disappears when I go to it because I'm not in the button div anymore.

Can anyone help?

*EDIT*

Thank you Moin Zaman, you answer covers about 90% of what I was looking for. One partular thing I need out of this is I need the entire original div to be clickable, aside from the area where link1 and link2 appear. The reason for this is, link 1 is a fixed size div box with a background image and no text. The hover state changes the background to a hover version of that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsbin.com/ohope4/3

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p,ul,li,form,button { margin:0; padding:0 }
    body { font:normal 62.5% arial; margin:20px }
    #button { background:#808080; padding:25px 10px 5px 10px; width:80px; text-align:center; }
    #button a { text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; font-size:1.2em; color:#000; }
    #link2,#link3 {display:none; font-size:0.9em;}
    #link1 { display:block; text-align:center; padding-bottom:25px }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="button">
        <a id="link1" href="#">link 1</a>
        <a id="link2" href="#">link 2</a>
        <a id="link3" href="#">link 3</a>        
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {
        var divButton = document.getElementById("button");
        divButton.onmouseover = ShowLinks;
        divButton.onmouseout = HideLinks;
    };  

  function ShowLinks(){
    document.getElementById('link2').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('link3').style.display = 'inline';
  }
  function HideLinks(){
    document.getElementById('link2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('link3').style.display = 'none';  
  }  
</script>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I'm looking for, the only other question I have would be, is there a way to remove the words "link 1" make the entire div clickable (linked to link1's location) when you click anywhere but link 2 and 3. The reason for this is, link 1 is a fixed size div box with a background image and no text. The hover state changes to a hover version of that image.

Comment: You can just attach a onclick event to the div. May I ask what is the scenario where you're wanting this feature? Also, Is there a reason why this needs to be done with JS? It is possible to do this with CSS alone. IE6 will need a little hack but otherwise if you don't care about IE6 it will work pretty much everywhere. I'll try and post a sample soon.

Comment: Basically my navigation has 5 links that run down the left half of the page. These links are div boxes with a background image representing the link (no text). When you hover over these, the background image shifts vertically by 100% (like this http://bit.ly/9leUSH). It makes it look like the link is glowing when you hover over it. One of these navigation links is a category with two subcategories. So in the example above, link 1 is the category and link 2 and 3 are the subcategories. I want link 1 to act the way it does but also add a couple extra options to speed up navigating the site.

Comment: Doesn't have to be java, I couldn't figure out a way to do it with just css.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using jquery? should make this a lot easier.  maybe something like:

html:

```
    <div>
        <a id="link1" href="#">link 1</a>
        <a id="link2" href="#">link 2</a>
        <a id="link3" href="#">link 3</a>        
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
$("a#linkone").hover(
    // when mouse enters
    function() {
        $("a#linketwo").show();
        $("a#linkthree").show();
    },
    // when mouse leaves
    function() {
        $("a#linketwo").hide();
        $("a#linkthree").hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: you don't need jQuery for this. esp. for something as simple as this

Comment: any site that uses javascript will probably be using enough of it to easily justify using jQuery IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this approach without JS: http://jsbin.com/osige4

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p,ul,li,form,button { margin:0; padding:0 }
      body { font:normal 62.5% arial; margin:20px }
      #button { background:#808080; padding:25px 10px 5px 10px; width:80px; text-align:center; cursor:pointer }
      #button a { text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; font-size:1.2em; color:#000; }
      #link2,#link3 {display:none; font-size:0.9em;}
      #link1 { display:block; text-align:center; padding-bottom:25px }
      #button:hover #link2, #button:hover #link3 { display:inline; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="button">
        <a id="link1" href="#">link 1</a>
        <a id="link2" href="#">link 2</a>
        <a id="link3" href="#">link 3</a>        
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: :O holy hell, I could kiss you. With a small tweak I got it to do exactly what I need. You've saved my sanity and my page looks awesome. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome! could you close out this question by accepting a comment as an answer?